# Delphi TListBox contents overflow when selecting (Win7, 32bit, themed)

Tags: delphi, listbox, paint

I've a TListBox on a Windows form with 966 elements in it.  When I click a button on my form, a subset of these strings are selected (roughly 200 of them).

If I now unfocus my application by clicking somewhere on the task bar, the entries from my TListBox bleed upward, so as they are visible above the boundaries of the TListBox.  They are thankfully bleeding out behind the TGroupBox component which is directly above them - however this still looks extrememly unpolished.

I'm able to reproduce this only on one Win 7 x64 machine using the Aero theme (I've another Win 7 x64 laptop which doesn't exhibit the same problem with the same theme setting).

I've tried issuing a PostMessage( Self.Handle, WM_PAINT, 0, 0) directly after changing the select status, preceded by a ListBox.Refresh.  This doesn't help.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Please advise if you need more details.

Cheers, Duncan

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem on Windows 7 64-bit, Delphi 2009. Are you sure this is related to the large number of list items? Try to narrow down the problem. Also: What is a `TSelectBox`? I suppose you mean a `TListBox`.

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, sorry, I did mean TListBox.  I'm also unable to reproduce this on any other computer. The other computers I've tested this on do have Aero, but all have discrete graphics adaptors (the problem computer uses an Intel Integrated adaptor).

Comment: Then first step I'd try is to update the graphic driver...

Comment: Windows delegates everything it can to the video driver, so machines with different driver may produce different results. Did you try safe mode (MS's own driver), or when disabling video acceleration?

Comment: If you're not doing some bizarro ownerdraw code, then I suspect the video driver.

Comment: What are your DPI settings? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the XPManifest unit, or have you enabled themes for your app? If so, try not using it to see what happens. It can be very bad if you dont have a good video card.

My 2 cents? Avoid using themes at all. It simple does not work very well.

Comment: -1 It's not *your* choice not to use themes. It's the person whose computer your app is running on. Secondly, the OP already said that Aero was in use and that a test was run with Aero on another machine that did not show the problem.

Comment: @Ken White I disagree with you. It is my choice not to use themes because I am the app developer and I know what works and what does not. Im my case, i like to use DevExpress skins library and avoid the bugged delphi theme unit. And as i said before (and I can see you did not read it) themes can be very bad if you dont have a good video card. He tried on another computer, yes, but it has the same video card? It is the same computer?

Comment: @Ken White And what I mean when i say "Avoid using themes at all", is "Does not use Delphi's theme unit at all". You can all other good solutions, like DevExpress has.

Comment: I just said you should try without themes to see what happens. I guess it is a good place to start.